# Can't get My Advanced Custom Field Label to display in my theme

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I can't get my Advanced Custom Field Label to display in my theme.

I want to achieve something like this

```
$field_name = "doc_author";
$field = get_field_object($field_name);

echo $field['label'] . ': ' . $field['value'];
```

I can display the field value like this

```
$buffy .= get_post_meta($this->post->ID, "document_author", true);
```

How can I display both the Label and the Value?

Answer (score 1):

Your field names are probably wrong.

In the first bit of code you are using "doc_author" and in the second one, which you say is working, your field is called "document_author".

Using "document_author" as field name with the first code-bit will solve your issue.

```
$field_name = "document_author";
$field = get_field_object($field_name);

echo $field['label'] . ': ' . $field['value'];
```